# Highlight with fuzziness and ngram

Tags: elasticsearch

I guess the title of the topic spoiled you enough :D

I use edge_ngram and highlight to build an autocomplete search. I have added fuzziness in the query to allow users to mispell their search, but it brokes a bit the highlight.

When i write `Sport` this is what I get :

```
<em>Spor</em>t
<em>Spor</em>t mécanique
<em>Spor</em>t nautique
```

I guess it's because it matches with the token `spor` generated by the ngram tokenizer.

The query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": {
                            "query": "sport",
                            "operator": "and",
                            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase_prefix": {
                        "name.raw": {
                            "query": "sport"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }   
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "name": {
              "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the mapping:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "partialAnalyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer",
                    "filter": ["asciifolding", "lowercase"]
                },
                "keywordAnalyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": ["asciifolding", "lowercase"]
                },
                "searchAnalyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["asciifolding", "lowercase"]
                }
            },

            "tokenizer": {
                "ngram_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": "1",
                    "max_gram": "15",
                    "token_chars": [ "letter", "digit" ]
                }
            }
        }
    },

    "mappings": {
        "place": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index_analyzer": "partialAnalyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "searchAnalyzer",
                    "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "keywordAnalyzer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add a new match clause without fuzziness in the query to try to match the keyword **before** the match with fuzziness but it changed nothing.

```
'match': {
   'name': {
   'query': 'sport',
   'operator': 'and'
}
```

Any idea how I can handle this?

Regards, Raphaël

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that with [highlight_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#_highlight_query) I guess

Try this in your highlighting query.

```
"highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "name": {
        "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
        "highlight_query": {
          "match": {
            "name.raw": {
                "query": "spotr",
                "fuzziness": 2
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hello, I tried it, it works with "well spelled" words, but if I write a mispelled word (E.g: `spotr` instead of `sport`), nothing is highlighted anymore.

Comment: I added `fuzziness` of 2, could you please check it again?

Comment: Same issues than the initial question with fuzziness (it only hightlight "spor") :(

Comment: _sport_ is a five letter word and `max edit distance` is one for 5 letter words in ES by default and hence _spotr_ cant be converted to _sport_ because it requires two operations and hence the edit distance is 2.  Refer to [fuzziness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzziness.html) section for more info

Comment: I tried it on my machine and It worked. I inserted sport and ran the fuzzy query with 'spotr" and it highlighted sport.

Comment: It's because you made a little mistake, you query the field "name.raw" (with a keyword tokenizer) instead of the field "name" (with the ngram tokenizer). But thank you anyway, I'm still trying a lot of things with "highlight_query" but I can't find a way to prioritize the full keyword instead of an ngram part :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95497/discussion-between-chintanshah25-and-raphael-malie).